# Allocate a color gradient to a function in java

Tags: java, image

I have to make a project for university. We have to simulate the growing of a disease. The simulation code is already working for me, but we had to insert the population from an image that display areas in the region which are correlated to a color gradient (like red means xy people per sqaure kilometer and yellow means yz people per square kilometer ...). Black pixels, and white pixels mean that there is no population at these area. How can such a function/algorithm look like? For example the image looks like this [image](https://www.google.de/search?q=bev%C3%B6lkerungsdichte&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT1LqslPrUAhWKbFAKHblJCkkQ_AUIBigB&biw=1440&bih=816#imgrc=_CbVRroTclXgJM:), but i have no legend i just have the total population of the area?

What kind of algorithms can i use to solve my problem? I have no ideas how to deal with colors in such a kind of problem i first tried to weigth the red, green and blue part but thats not really working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please narrow your question down to a specific coding question that would be on-topic for this site.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a good fit for questions of the form "how do i write code to do this?". You'd be much better off writing an attempt at something, even if it's horrible and hardly works and posting that instead.

Comment: Sry i just wanted to ask for proposals on how to solve that problem. I thougth it was clear! I am searching for an algorithm or an idea on how to start with that problem and not a specific code fragement to use. I will edit the question to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a linear gradient from yellow to red, that's relatively simple.

Pure red in RGB is `(255, 0, 0)`. Makes sense, right? To get red, you max out the red component, and have no green or blue.

Pure yellow is `(255, 255, 0)` which is a perfectly even mix of red and green with no blue.

So, as you can see, in both cases `R=255` and `B=0`. By altering the amount of green you'll get something in the middle. Your scale therefore has 255 distinct values - it's just a matter of mapping from population density to a value between 0 and 255.

```
private static final int MAX_RGB_VALUE = 255;

int getGreen(final int maxDensity, final int minDensity, final int density)
{
    // we could/should check that minDensity < density < maxDensity else
    // we'll get divide by zero errors

    final int delta = maxDensity - minDensity;
    final float relativeDensity = density / (float) delta;
    return Math.round(relativeDensity * MAX_RGB_VALUE);
}
```

and then your final colour would look something like:

```
final int green = getGreen(maxDensity, minDensity, density);
Color colour = new Color(MAX_RGB_VALUE, green, MAX_RGB_VALUE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem is that  Colors doent start at the maximum values so yellow can have the color (242,220,0) how can i display this with that code